# How to parameterized jdbc request to insert values?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jmeter

I have below Query in the JDBC request in jmeter. I need to parametrized each and every field in the query to send values.ID should be increment one by one while other values generated as random values.
Appreciate if anyone can give idea on this.

```
insert into product.test (id,business_center,item_group,attribute_group,created_on,modified_by)
values ('${id}','bc','ig','ag','2021-08-17 13:03:34','Test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
insert into product.test (id,business_center,item_group,attribute_group,created_on,modified_by)
values ('${__counter(FALSE,)}',
'${__RandomString(2,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}',
'${__RandomString(2,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}',
'${__RandomString(2,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}',
'${__RandomDate(yyyy-MM-dd,now,2022-12-31,,)} 13:03:34',
'${__RandomString(4,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}${__RandomString(2,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}')
```

[image]

should do the trick for you.

More information:

- [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function
- [__RandomDate()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate) function
- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: Thank you very much @Dimitri T Well explained.Its really helpful for me to complete my task.